# Error rowGroup Datatable in PHP - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'RowGroup')

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
function PERSYARATAN() {
    $('#persyaratan_table').DataTable({
        "columns": [{
            "orderable" : true,
            "class"     : "text-center",
            "width"     : "5%",
        },
        {
            "orderable" : false,
            "class"     : "text-left"
        },
        {
            "orderable" : false,
            "class"     : "text-left"
        },
        {
            "orderable" : true,
            "class"     : "text-left",
            // "class"     : "hide_column",
        },
        {
            "orderable" : true,
            "class"     : "text-left"
        },
        
        ],
        order: [[3, 'asc']],
        rowgroup: {
            dataSrc: 3
        },
       
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "autoWidth" : false,
        "searching" : true,
        "stateSave" : true,
        "bDestroy"  : true,
        "iDisplayLenght" : 10,
        "sPaginationType": "simple_numbers",
        "language": {
            "url": "../plugins/datatables/Indonesian.json"
        },
        "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
            $.ajax({
                "url"   : "/persyaratanperaturanizin",
                "type"  : "GET",
                "data"  : data,
                "error" : function(xhr) {
                    ERROR_ALERT(xhr);
                    callback({
                        draw: 1,
                        data: [],
                        recordsTotal: 0,
                        recordsFiltered: 0
                    });
                },
                "success": function (data) {
                    var respons = data.respons;
                    if (respons.success == 1) {
                        no = respons.data.data.lenght;
                        callback(respons.data);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Thats my js code datatable

i want to use row group datatable and i get this error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'RowGroup')
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6STt.png

i already call

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.3/css/rowGroup.bootstrap4.min.css
```

and

```
 https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.3/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js
```

how fix this error

Comment: You put a JS function inside a <pre> tag. And what does any of this have to do with PHP?

Comment: no, sorry, just typo